# What happens when normal force is greater than $mg$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

I know what happens when **mg** is greater than **Normal force** .But I am little bit confused of the concept of **Normal force**.I mean imagine the situation Normal force is greater than mg.

Comment: What about the concept of normal force confuses you?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you just unaccept my answer?

Comment: @BobD  Well , I just wanted to edit my question which may slightly differ from what I have asked before but without changing the concept. So just thought of unaccept the answer  so that the answer itself can be edited later. Just as asked I am keeping that answer again accepted untill I edit my question.Thank You. :)

Comment: OK. But there is no need to unaccept my answer in order to edit your question unless you feel my answer would no longer apply to your edited question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can you imagine the situation when Normal force is greater than mg ?

Yes. When an additional downward force $F$ is applied to a mass $m$ resting on a horizontal surface, the normal force is $F_{N}=F+mg$. It can also be less than $mg$. An example is the normal force on an incline plane with an angle of $θ$ due to a mass $m$. Then $F_{N}=mg$ cos θ.

A normal force is the component of a contact force that is perpendicular to the surface that an object contacts. A mass $m$ resting on a horizontal surface is only one example of a normal force.

Hope this helps.

Comment: okay thats helped me.

Comment: @Malavika Glad it  helped. You should also note that a normal force need not involve gravity at all. A horizontal force on a vertical wall results in a normal force on the wall and gravity is not involved.

Comment: Another easy example is when you are accelerating upwards in an elevator :)

Comment: Also, for a toy car going around a loop, there is centripetal force involved.  At the bottom of the loop, the normal force must equal $mg$ + $mv^2/r$.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean normal reaction, then obviously it can be greater than mg (weight). For example: when pushing an object at an angle to horizontal from above. What is your confusion?